# GetResponse exception

Tags: c#, exception, httpwebrequest

I have the following problem:
i have the code

```
string url = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id=123&client_secret=qqq&code=123&redirect_uri=myurl.com";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

// here I've got my exception  
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("response = " + reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I perfom this code in console app and it works fine. But when I use this code in asp.net application it fails with exception "unable to connect to the remote server". Црн does it happen? And how could I fix it?

Comment: when using in the asp.net application, do you mean this is happening when debugging locally or on the server?

Comment: it happends when i debug locally

Answer (score 0):

Add that into your web.config and try again:

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress="http://address:port" bypassonlocal="false" />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any specific reason as to why this is failing, I have the below near identical code in my asp.net application. Can you see any requests being made over the network, download http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and examine the traffic going out/ or not.

```
    var webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToGetInfo);

            using (var response = webRequest1.GetResponse())
            {
                var stream1 = response.GetResponseStream();

            }
```